# How to set environment specific value in Blazor index.html?

Tags: deployment, blazor-webassembly, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

our Blazor web use Google RECAPTCHA and we have the following JS in the index.html file in wwwroot

and the GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY is different in DEV, QA and Production, what is the best way to set that GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY accordingly depends on the environment?

We are using Azure pipeline to deploy to all different environment .. also need it to work locally in Visual Studio.

Thanks very much!
John

I tried using azure pipeline to replace token and it did not work very well.